# Local Storage properties

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

```
export const addNabuaItem = (item = [], count = 0, next = f => f) => {
let nabua = [];
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (localStorage.getItem('nabua')) {  //If it has cart in local storage then ...
        //NOTE to convert json to object 
        // get product from local storage 
        nabua = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nabua'));
    }
    //NOTE store it as an Array of Object 
    nabua.push({
        ...item,
        count: 1 // NOTE intitial count after item was added by a user is one
    });   
    // remove duplicates
    // build an Array from new Set and turn it back into array using Array.from
    // so that later we can re-map it
    // new set will only allow unique values in it
    // so pass the ids of each object/product
    // If the loop tries to add the same value again, it'll get ignored
    // ...with the array of ids we got on when first map() was used
    // run map() on it again and return the actual product from the cart

    nabua = Array.from(new Set(nabua.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
        return nabua.find(p => p._id === id);
    });

    localStorage.setItem('nabua', JSON.stringify(nabua));
    next();
}
};
```

This is my code for adding products to cart (store in Local Storage). I would like to add only a specific property of the product such as only name, price, and description because I don't want to store unnecessary properties in Local storage. How can I do that ?

Below is my console of local storage that contain product Object,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhTmj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another map when you are assigning to `nabua` so it looks like this:

```
nabua = Array.from(new Set(nabua.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
    return nabua.find(p => p._id === id);
})
.map(item => ({
  field1: item.field1,
  field2: item.field2
}));
```

And make `field1`/`field2` whatever field you like. So if you want name, description and price, it can look something like this

```
.map(item => ({
      name: item.name,
      description: item.description,
      price: item.price
}));
```